# gimp создать изображение из слоя

Tags: графика

Как сохранить слой из файла psd в jpeg?

Comment: Сделать все остальные слои невидимыми и экспортировать.

Comment: А если у меня много мелких картинок разбросанных по холсту? Чтобы они были экспортировались сразу в своём размере?